# Error al conectar mySQL con NetBeans

Tags: java, java-ee, servlets, mysqlconnector

Disculpe he intentado hacer conectar un servlet con MySQL. El ejercicio indica que tengo que realizar MySQL server, no puedo usar XAMPP O WAMP server. He realizado varias configuraciones y nada funciona. 
Estos son los errores que me indica Netbeans.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la configuración que tiene la contraseña en root
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es la segunda parte

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos son los errores que aparecen en Netbeans
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor me podria ayudar la verdad necesito resolver este problema lo más pronto posible para empezar un proyecto que involucra que el uso de MySQL y Java.

Comment: Se que la pregunta dice que no se debe usar xampp o wamp,  pero espero que no estes entonces tratando de usar xampp o mamp en ese puerto a la vez que tienes corriendo tu servidor en  netbeans... si no pues si o si habrá un conflicto.

Comment: De hecho los tenia, pero los desinstale solo tengo MySQL server, shell y Workbench. No se si deba a un error de instalación